# Cyclic subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

> Find the smallest natural number n ∈ ℕ such that $S_n$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order 101.

Proof: We seek the smallest n such that Sn contains a permutation of order 101. Permutation can be written in terms of a collection of disjoint cycles. Let  σ  be permutation of order 101 consisting of q disjoint cycle, and let the length be ki,…,kq. The order of the element will be equal to the least common multiple of the length cycle. 
 By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, any number can be uniquely decomposed into a product of powers of prime numbers. It is easy to see that 101 =1 • 101, so each of the ki's must have a prime decomposition consisting of 1 & 101. Hence smallest natural number is 1

---

Is this correct or I am missing? If missing what will be the correct way?

Comment: Are you sayng that the group of permutations on $1$ element contains a permutation of order $101$ ?!?

Comment: Yes. I guess. But is this a correct way to find a smallest natural number of cyclic group of order 101?

Comment: What's the smallest natural number of a cyclic group?

Comment: 1 is it? coz if u do the LCM of 101 the only result will be 1 and 101. So 1 is the smallest?   Help me guys to understand

Comment: @user120 , $\;|S_1|=1\;$ , so you think this group can have an element of order $\;101\;$ ?! Even mistakes must have some minimal logic and argumentation, at least at some level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, every permutation can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles.  The order of such a product is given by the least common multiple of the cycle lengths.  The smallest $n$ such that $S_n$ contains a permutation of that form is the *sum* of the cycle lengths.

Since 101 is prime, the only disjoint cycle expression of a permutation of order 101 is a single cycle of length 101.  So $n$ = 101.

A more interesting problem is given by replacing 101 with a composite number, such as 12.

Comment: So therefor smallest will be 101? right

Comment: such as 12 then it will be 3x2^2. Therefore will be 4 option 
(1) k1 = 3 • 2, k2 = 2
(2) k1 = 2, k2 = 2, k3 = 3
(3) k1 = 2^2 • 3
(4) k1 = 2^2 , k2 = 3
From this 4 option there will option 4 which is correct right?

Comment: Take the sums of the cycle lengths in each of the four options, and see which one is smallest.

Comment: What will be your answer?